# Mysqli query not working

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve all the maximum disease use in an year.I have a table named view_accepted_appoinments which has column disease and date. I am trying this query but it is not working

```
select distinct doc_specilization as disease,
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y') as year,
count(Distinct doc_specilization) as count
from view_accepted_appoinments
group by year
order by year desc;
```

The query returns this which gives wrong disease name

```
+--------------+------+-------+
| disease      | YEAR | count |
+--------------+------+-------+
| Primary Care | 2014 |     8 |
| Primary Care | 2013 |     1 |
+--------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: not working in the sense??? can you be more clear about the error message you are getting or the data displayed as output is not same as the output you are expecting and can u also show us the columns of the table

Comment: Does this query return you the expected record set when executed through a database client like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question -- so the issue is with the query itself, not PHP or MySQLi, so I removed those two tags.

Comment: Suppose Heart Disease is more in year 2014 which happens to 10 patient in an year which in result gives me Heart Disease and it's occurences with value 10.
I want to show that type of result yearly

Comment: @budhajeewa yeah issue with the query can you try to solve?

Comment: @Zeeshan: Try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27461444/445438.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select distinct d , spec,c from(
      select date_format(date,"%Y") as d,
      doctor, doc_specilization as spec,
      count(doc_specilization) as  c from
      view_accepted_appoinments
      group by doc_specilization, d)f
      group by d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT doc_specialization AS disease,
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') AS year,
COUNT(doc_specialization) AS count,
FROM view_accepted_appoinments
GROUP BY doc_specialization, year
ORDER BY year DESC, doc_specialization ASC;
```

Comment: This error occurs

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM view_accepted_appoinments GROUP BY doc_specialization, year ORDER BY year D' at line 4

Comment: @Zeeshan: Can you provide a dump -- preferably with a small amount of actual data -- of your database? So that I can import it and test?

Comment: i created a logical table(view) for that .